# Swift TableViewCell Image like setting app on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

**Problem:**

> I want to replicate the settings app left cell.UIImage with sfSymbols to a T
> programmatically not using a nib or custom cell.

I am trying to replicate the settings app sfSymbol images on the left of the cell (as seen in the image).

Is it possible to do this without creating a custom cell and only using TableViewCell?

The issue I am having is the imageView background color border while sizing a sfSymbol inside of it. The problem is creating the the sfSymbol to fit in the background just as settings app does.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        
        
        cell?.textLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
        cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        
        let item = tableItems[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = item.title

         //let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 25, weight: .regular, scale: .small)
         //cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: item.systemImageName, withConfiguration: config)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: item.systemImageName)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)

        cell?.imageView?.backgroundColor = tableItems[indexPath.row].backgroundColor
       
        if let imageView = cell?.imageView, imageView.transform == .identity {
           imageView.transform = imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.50, y: 0.50)
           imageView.contentMode = .center
           imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        }

        
        return cell!
    }
```

**My goal is to replicate this without creating a custom cell or nib.Perhaps a custom container view programmatically.**
[image]

Output (What my code lookes like): I need it to replicate the settings app images in the image above.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having with the image view. Can you update your question with a picture of the results you are getting? (Just show one or two rows, not an entire screen capture).

Comment: @HangarRash I edited with a picture. You can see im having issues replicate settings when it comes to the tableView cell.imageView. I pretty much want any sfSymbol to look like the settings app in iPhone.

Comment: If you add "a custom container view programmatically" then you are creating a custom cell. You don't need to use a nib file, but you will need to create a subclass of `UITableviewCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Replicate settings app Icons (sfSymbols) with without a nib or custom cell.

You need to:

- Create a custom UIImageView for the SF Symbol
- Set the background color and corner radius
- Convert the custom UIImageView to UIImage
- Convert the visual content of a UIView, including its subviews, into an image (UIImage).
- Set the custom image as the cell's imageView image

This will allow you to replicate the settings app left side icons of the tableView cell with sfSymbols, corner radius, and background colors.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        
        
        cell?.textLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
        cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        
        let item = tableItems[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = item.title
        
        
        // Create a custom UIImageView for the SF Symbol
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 15, weight: .regular, scale: .small)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: item.systemImageName,withConfiguration: config)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        
        // Set the background color and corner radius
        imageView.backgroundColor = tableItems[indexPath.row].backgroundColor
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        // Convert the custom UIImageView to UIImage
        if let compositeImage = image(from: imageView) {
            // Set the custom image as the cell's imageView image
            cell?.imageView?.image = compositeImage
        }
        
        return cell!
    }


    func image(from view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            view.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The use of fixed parameters, such as type size, seems like it could have problems. A test case showing it works even for users who have expanded their text size would be valuable

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 14.0

You should take advantage of **UIListContentConfiguration** introduced in iOS 14 and also the style property of your UITableView with the initialiser `init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style)`.

You could create your UITableView like this below:

```
private func configure() {
    title = "Settings"
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .insetGrouped)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: settingsCellReuseIdentifier)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

And your UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    Settings.allCases.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: settingsCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()

    // Configure content.
    content.image = Settings.allCases[indexPath.row].image
    content.text = Settings.allCases[indexPath.row].name
    content.secondaryText = Settings.allCases[indexPath.row].content
    cell.accessoryType = Settings.allCases[indexPath.row].accessory

    // Customize appearance.
    content.imageProperties.tintColor = Settings.allCases[indexPath.row].color
    
    cell.contentConfiguration = content

    return cell
}
```

Just as a helper, the enum below:

```
enum Settings: CaseIterable {

 case wifi, icloud

 var name: String {
     switch self {
     case .wifi: return "Wi-Fi"
     case .icloud: return "iCloud"
     }
 }

 var content: String? {
     switch self {
     case .wifi: return nil
     case .icloud: return "Apple ID"
     }
 }

 var image: UIImage {
     switch self {
     case .wifi: return UIImage(systemName: "wifi.square.fill")!
     case .icloud: return UIImage(systemName: "icloud.square.fill")!
     }
 }

 var color: UIColor {
     switch self {
     case .wifi, .icloud: return .link
     }
 }

 var accessory: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType {
     switch self {
     case .wifi, .icloud: return .disclosureIndicator
     }
 }
}
```

This way you avoid creating any kind of custom cells and without a custom container view.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1UOF.png)